# OpenCV importing error

Tags: python, opencv

after importing the cv2 library into python, the following error showed:

```
Traceback(most recent call):
file"<stdin>",line1,in <module>
Attribute Error:'module' object has no attribute '_version_'
```

What should I do?

Answer (score 4):

you want `__version__` , not `_version_` ;)

```
import cv2;
>>> cv2._version_
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute '_version_'
>>> cv2.__version__
'3.0.0-dev'
>>>
```

Comment: new to it...turns out i'm an idiot :-P ..anyways thanks for the answers

Comment: tumb tuesday, happens ;)

Answer (score 2):

After `import cv2` statement, use `dir(cv2)` statement which will return list of all method of the `cv2` module.

e.g. For `csv` module because On my machine `cv2` is not install.

```
>>> import csv
>>> dir(csv)
['Dialect', 'DictReader', 'DictWriter', 'Error', 'QUOTE_ALL', 'QUOTE_MINIMAL', 'QUOTE_NONE', 'QUOTE_NONNUMERIC', 'Sniffer', 'StringIO', '_Dialect', '__all__', '__builtins__', '__doc__', '__file__', '__name__', '__package__', '__version__', 'excel', 'excel_tab', 'field_size_limit', 'get_dialect', 'list_dialects', 're', 'reader', 'reduce', 'register_dialect', 'unregister_dialect', 'writer']
>>> csv.__version__
'1.0'
```